# 2 columns how to align content vertically start from same point using flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a child component being called 2 times to create 2 columns. I want the description in both columns to start from same point, even if the title in each column is 1 line, 3 lines etc. I do not want to apply `min-height` on the titles.

[image]

```
export default function App() {
  const Child = ({ backgroundColor, title, desc }) => {
    return (
      <div className={`relative  flex-1 ${backgroundColor} p-4`}>
      <div className="h-full overflow-hidden border-2 bg-white pb-20 flex flex-col justify-between">
        <div className="p-4 flex-1">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250" />
          <h2 className="font-Headingg mb-2 mt-2 overflow-auto text-2xl font-bold text-black">{title}</h2>
          <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap text-black">
            <span class="mr-2">Link 1</span>
            <span>Link 2</span>
          </div>
           <p className="text-md text-justify text-black">{desc}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="absolute bottom-0 flex flex-wrap items-center bg-slate-300 p-4">
          <p className="mb-2 mr-2 px-1 py-2 text-xs tracking-wide">Link #1</p>
          <p className="mb-2 mr-2 px-1 py-2 text-xs tracking-wide">Link #2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    )
  }

  return (
  <>
<div className="container mx-auto p-6">
  <div className="-mx-4 flex flex-shrink">
      <Child title="some title text" desc="some description" backgroundColor={'bg-yellow-200'} />
      <Child title="some title text which is longer which should cover atleast 2 lines" desc="a  description that is longer than the other description, but description should start on same point in both columns " backgroundColor={'bg-cyan-200'} />
  </div>
</div>
  </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to get the vertical position of the description elements, and add some `padding-top` to the one that would be positioned further up:

```
// Use `forwardRef` to direct the parent `ref` prop to the description element.
// Have a `descTop` prop that will be passed the the description element as its
// `padding-top`. This is optional and will be `null` by default (no value at
// all).
const Child = forwardRef(({ backgroundColor, title, desc, descTop = null }, ref) => {
  return (
    <div className={`relative  flex-1 ${backgroundColor} p-4`}>
    <div className="h-full overflow-hidden border-2 bg-white pb-20 flex flex-col justify-between">
      <div className="p-4 flex-1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/250/250" />
        <h2 className="font-Headingg mb-2 mt-2 overflow-auto text-2xl font-bold text-black">{title}</h2>
        <div class="mb-4 flex flex-wrap text-black">
          <span class="mr-2">Link 1</span>
          <span>Link 2</span>
        </div>
          <p className="text-md text-justify text-black" ref={ref} style={{ paddingTop: descTop }}>{desc}</p>
      </div>
      <div className="absolute bottom-0 flex flex-wrap items-center bg-slate-300 p-4">
        <p className="mb-2 mr-2 px-1 py-2 text-xs tracking-wide">Link #1</p>
        <p className="mb-2 mr-2 px-1 py-2 text-xs tracking-wide">Link #2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
});

const App = () => {
  // Have references to the description HTML elements.
  const child1Ref = useRef(null);
  const child2Ref = useRef(null);
  // State that has the vertical spacing difference.
  const [descTop, setDescTop] = useState(0);
  
  // Once the components have rendered:
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Get the vertical position of each child description element.
    const { top: top1 } = child1Ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const { top: top2 } = child2Ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    // Set the offset for the first child as the difference between the
    // vertical positions.
    setDescTop(top2 - top1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto p-6">
      <div className="-mx-4 flex flex-shrink">
        <Child title="some title text" desc="some description" backgroundColor={'bg-yellow-200'} ref={child1Ref} descTop={descTop} />
        <Child title="some title text which is longer which should cover atleast 2 lines" desc="a  description that is longer than the other description, but description should start on same point in both columns " backgroundColor={'bg-cyan-200'} ref={child2Ref} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```js
const { createElement, forwardRef, useState, useRef, useLayoutEffect } = React;
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;

const Child = forwardRef(({ backgroundColor, title, desc, descTop = null }, ref) => {
  return createElement('div', { className: `relative  flex-1 ${backgroundColor} p-4` },
    createElement('div', { className: 'h-full overflow-hidden border-2 bg-white pb-20 flex flex-col justify-between' },
      createElement('div', { className: 'p-4 flex-1' },
        createElement('img', { src: 'https://picsum.photos/250/250' }),
        createElement('h2', { className: 'font-Headingg mb-2 mt-2 overflow-auto text-2xl font-bold text-black' },
          title,
        ),
        createElement('div', { className: 'mb-4 flex flex-wrap text-black' },
          createElement('span', { className: 'mr-2' }, 'Link 1'),
          createElement('span', {}, 'Link 1'),
        ),
        createElement('p', { className: 'text-md text-justify text-black', ref, style: { paddingTop: descTop } }, desc),
      ),
      createElement('div', { className: 'absolute bottom-0 flex flex-wrap items-center bg-slate-300 p-4' },
        createElement('p', { className: 'mb-2 mr-2 px-1 py-2 text-xs tracking-wide' },
          'Link #1',
        ),
        createElement('p', { className: 'mb-2 mr-2 px-1 py-2 text-xs tracking-wide' },
          'Link #2',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const child1Ref = useRef(null);
  const child2Ref = useRef(null);
  const [descTop, setDescTop] = useState(0);
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const { top: top1 } = child1Ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const { top: top2 } = child2Ref.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setDescTop(top2 - top1);
  }, []);
  
  return createElement('div', { className: 'container mx-auto p-6' },
    createElement('div', { className: '-mx-4 flex flex-shrink' },
      createElement(Child, { title: 'some title text', desc: 'some description', backgroundColor: 'bg-yellow-200', descTop, ref: child1Ref }),
      createElement(Child, { title: 'some title text which is longer which should cover atleast 2 lines', desc: 'a  description that is longer than the other description, but description should start on same point in both columns', backgroundColor: 'bg-cyan-200', ref: child2Ref }),
    ),
  );
};

createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(createElement(App));
```

```css
/* ! tailwindcss v3.3.1 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com */*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box;border-width:0;border-style:solid;border-color:#e5e7eb}::after,::before{--tw-content:''}html{line-height:1.5;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-moz-tab-size:4;tab-size:4;font-family:ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";font-feature-settings:normal;font-variation-settings:normal}body{margin:0;line-height:inherit}hr{height:0;color:inherit;border-top-width:1px}abbr:where([title]){-webkit-text-decoration:underline dotted;text-decoration:underline dotted}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit}a{color:inherit;text-decoration:inherit}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,pre,samp{font-family:ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;font-size:1em}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}table{text-indent:0;border-color:inherit;border-collapse:collapse}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;font-weight:inherit;line-height:inherit;color:inherit;margin:0;padding:0}button,select{text-transform:none}[type=button],[type=reset],[type=submit],button{-webkit-appearance:button;background-color:transparent;background-image:none}:-moz-focusring{outline:auto}:-moz-ui-invalid{box-shadow:none}progress{vertical-align:baseline}::-webkit-inner-spin-button,::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type=search]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}summary{display:list-item}blockquote,dd,dl,figure,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,hr,p,pre{margin:0}fieldset{margin:0;padding:0}legend{padding:0}menu,ol,ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}textarea{resize:vertical}input::placeholder,textarea::placeholder{opacity:1;color:#9ca3af}[role=button],button{cursor:pointer}:disabled{cursor:default}audio,canvas,embed,iframe,img,object,svg,video{display:block;vertical-align:middle}img,video{max-width:100%;height:auto}[hidden]{display:none}*, ::before, ::after{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::-webkit-backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }::backdrop{--tw-border-spacing-x:0;--tw-border-spacing-y:0;--tw-translate-x:0;--tw-translate-y:0;--tw-rotate:0;--tw-skew-x:0;--tw-skew-y:0;--tw-scale-x:1;--tw-scale-y:1;--tw-pan-x: ;--tw-pan-y: ;--tw-pinch-zoom: ;--tw-scroll-snap-strictness:proximity;--tw-ordinal: ;--tw-slashed-zero: ;--tw-numeric-figure: ;--tw-numeric-spacing: ;--tw-numeric-fraction: ;--tw-ring-inset: ;--tw-ring-offset-width:0px;--tw-ring-offset-color:#fff;--tw-ring-color:rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);--tw-ring-offset-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-ring-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow:0 0 #0000;--tw-shadow-colored:0 0 #0000;--tw-blur: ;--tw-brightness: ;--tw-contrast: ;--tw-grayscale: ;--tw-hue-rotate: ;--tw-invert: ;--tw-saturate: ;--tw-sepia: ;--tw-drop-shadow: ;--tw-backdrop-blur: ;--tw-backdrop-brightness: ;--tw-backdrop-contrast: ;--tw-backdrop-grayscale: ;--tw-backdrop-hue-rotate: ;--tw-backdrop-invert: ;--tw-backdrop-opacity: ;--tw-backdrop-saturate: ;--tw-backdrop-sepia: }.container{width:100%}@media (min-width: 640px){.container{max-width:640px}}@media (min-width: 768px){.container{max-width:768px}}@media (min-width: 1024px){.container{max-width:1024px}}@media (min-width: 1280px){.container{max-width:1280px}}@media (min-width: 1536px){.container{max-width:1536px}}.absolute{position:absolute}.relative{position:relative}.bottom-0{bottom:0px}.-mx-4{margin-left:-1rem;margin-right:-1rem}.mx-auto{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.mb-2{margin-bottom:0.5rem}.mb-4{margin-bottom:1rem}.mr-2{margin-right:0.5rem}.mt-2{margin-top:0.5rem}.flex{display:flex}.h-full{height:100%}.flex-1{flex:1 1 0%}.flex-shrink{flex-shrink:1}.flex-col{flex-direction:column}.flex-wrap{flex-wrap:wrap}.items-center{align-items:center}.justify-between{justify-content:space-between}.overflow-auto{overflow:auto}.overflow-hidden{overflow:hidden}.border-2{border-width:2px}.bg-cyan-200{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(165 243 252 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-slate-300{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(203 213 225 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-white{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.bg-yellow-200{--tw-bg-opacity:1;background-color:rgb(254 240 138 / var(--tw-bg-opacity))}.p-4{padding:1rem}.p-6{padding:1.5rem}.px-1{padding-left:0.25rem;padding-right:0.25rem}.py-2{padding-top:0.5rem;padding-bottom:0.5rem}.pb-20{padding-bottom:5rem}.text-justify{text-align:justify}.text-2xl{font-size:1.5rem;line-height:2rem}.text-xs{font-size:0.75rem;line-height:1rem}.font-bold{font-weight:700}.tracking-wide{letter-spacing:0.025em}.text-black{--tw-text-opacity:1;color:rgb(0 0 0 / var(--tw-text-opacity))}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

This is a rudimentary example for the very particular situation you have presented. Some things to watch out for:

- The code assumes the first `<Child>` always has a shorter title than the second `<Child>` – you will want to look at reworking the logic to pass the offset to the correct `<Child>`.
- You may need to alter the offset depending on if the parent element resizes.
- You will need to adapt the code if the intention is for there to be a variable amount of `<Child>` elements.